# How do I prove that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)$ is absolutely convergent for $0 \leq x < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Consider the infinite product

> > $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n).$$

Prove that the above infinite product is absolutely convergent for $0 \leq x < 1.$

I have considered the sequence of partial products $\{F_m(x) \}$ where $$F_m (x) = \prod_{n=1}^{m} (1-x^n).$$ Then I have observed that $F_{m+1} (x) = (1 - x^{m+1}) F_m (x).$ If $0 \leq x <1$ then $F_{m+1} (x) \leq F_m (x).$ So the sequence of partial products is monotone decreasing and bounded below by $0.$ So for every $0 \leq x < 1$ the sequence $\{F_m(x) \}$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below by $0$ and therefore it is convergent. Since for $0 \leq x < 1$  the sequence $\{F_m (x) \}$ is a sequence of positive terms (as each term is the product of finitely many positive terms) so we can conclude that the sequence $\{F_m (x) \}$ is absolutely convergent for each $0 \leq x < 1.$ Therefore for each $0 \leq x <1$ the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)$ is absolutely convergent as well.

Is the above argument ok? Please verify it.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an absolute convergence of a product?

Comment: If you multiply two numbers, both in the interval $(0,1]$, in what interval does the end-result sit? Do you know what induction is?

Comment: I don't know if this would help but you can use pentagonal number theorem to simplify the product

Comment: @Darkai I haven't studied Euler's pentagonal number theorem. But yes I am now studying the subject partition theory.

Comment: @Wojowu I don't know that. Perhaps that was the problem when I did the solution. That is why I post my solution here as I was bit unsure about my solution. Can you tell me what is meant by absolute convergence of products? Is it different from what we know about the sums?

Comment: @user334732 I know that if we multiply two numbers in $(0,1]$ the end result sits also in $(0,1].$ It's pretty easy. The answer to your second question is also in the affirmative direction. **"YES" I DO KNOW INDUCTION.**

Comment: By definition, a product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+a_n)$ is convergent if the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+|x_n|)$ is convergent.

Comment: Where do I find that? Can you share me some notes available online for free which I can be able to download and study it on my own?

Comment: I am studying the topics "Partition theory" from the book Analytic Number Theory written by Tom M. Apostol.  There I first found such infinite products. But I don't have any formal intro to that infinite product stuff in real analysis before. So It seems troublesome for me at some stage to understand the reasoning given in this book. So any help regarding that will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also note that by the convention I've learned, if the sequence of partial products has limit 0, then that's considered to be a divergent product.  So, under this convention, your proof would be incomplete since it doesn't show the limit is nonzero (which it does turn out to be).

Comment: Can you explain why is it so @Daniel Schepler?

Comment: Take the log of the partial products to convert to a series convergence question, then use limit comparison test of $\log(1-x^n)$ with $-x^n$.

Comment: @mathmaniac. do you already have that $[0,1]$ is compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition, the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ is absolutely convergent if $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + |a_n|)$ is convergent. Now observe that $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + |a_n|)$ is convergent iff $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log (1 + |a_n|)$ is convergent. Also observe that $\log (1 + |a_n|) \leq |a_n|,$ for all $n \in \Bbb N.$ Therefore we can conclude that the infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 + a_n)$ is absolutely convergent iff the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

In this case $a_n = - x^n,$ for all $n \in \Bbb N.$ So in order to show that the given infinite product $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^n)$ is absolutely convergent for each $0 \leq x < 1$ we need only to show that the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$ is convergent for each $0 \leq x <1.$ Which is a very well known result and I leave the details for you to verify.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

> $$\prod_{n=1}^{m}{(1-x^n)}=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m}{\ln(1-x^n)}\right)$$ 
>   $$= \exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^{m}{\sum_{\sigma=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{\sigma n}}{\sigma}}}\right)=\exp\left(-\sum_{\sigma=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sigma}}\sum_{n=1}^{m}{x^{\sigma n}}\right) $$

Comment: Now $$\begin{align} \exp \left (- \sum\limits_{\sigma = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {\sigma} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} x^{\sigma n} \right ) & = \exp \left ( -\sum\limits_{\sigma = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {\sigma} \cdot \frac {x^{\sigma} (1 -  x^{\sigma m})} {1 - x^{\sigma}} \right ).\end{align}$$ What can be done then @HAMIDINE SOUMARE?

Comment: Can you say what was wrong in my steps @HAMIDINE SOUMARE in the body of the question?